# Using lambda to filter stream and throw an exception

Tags: java, exception, lambda, java-stream

Currently our implementation of a base method using `Set<String> clients` was as follows -

```
if (clients.isEmpty()) {
    throw new InvalidClientException();
}

for (String client : clients) {
    if (!myMay.containsKey(client)) {
        throw new InvalidClientException(client);
    }
}
```

I tried converting it using lambda expression as follows -

```
clients.stream().filter(client -> !myMay.containsKey(client) || clients.isEmpty())
            .forEach(InvalidClientException::new);
```

But this seems to be not working the same way, is the parameterised constructor call a miss here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, if the set is empty, the lambda passed to forEach won't be executed: an empty stream is empty, and filtering it won't add any element to it. Only potentially remove some.

Second, the lambda creates an exception. But it doesn't throw it.

You can use

```
if (clients.isEmpty() || clients.stream().anyMatch(client -> !myMay.containsKey(client))) {
    throw new InvalidClientException();
}
```

EDIT: I missed the fact that you wanted to pass the (first?) client not in the set to the exception. To do that, you can do

```
if (clients.isEmpty()) {
    throw new InvalidClientException();
}

clients.stream()
       .filter(client -> !myMay.containsKey(client))
       .findAny() // or .findFirst()
       .ifPresent(client -> {
           throw new InvalidClientException(client);
       });
```

That will only work if the exception is a runtime exception, though, because you can't throw a checked exception from a Consumer. If it's a checked exception and you really want to keep it a checked exception, you can use

```
if (clients.isEmpty()) {
    throw new InvalidClientException();
}

Optional<String> wrongClient = 
    clients.stream()
           .filter(client -> !myMay.containsKey(client))
           .findAny();
if (wrongClient.isPresent()) {
    throw new InvalidClientException(wrongClient.get());
}
```

Comment: ohk, no way to use filter while streaming and throw the exception as well?

Comment: also how to handle `throw new InvalidClientException(client)` here?

Comment: You don't want to dilter. You want to find if an element of the stream is not in the myMay set. That's what `anyMatch()` does. Throwing an exception for every element not in the set doesn't make much sense, since as soon as the exception is thrown, the loop will stop.

Comment: i meant the parameterised call to `InvalidClientException(client)` where i need to pass the clients name which is invalid as well

Comment: the updated version doesn't seem to be working on my IDE, for the `ifPresent` part

Comment: Sorry, you need curly braces, as shown in my edited answer. And the exception must be a runtime exception, of course.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122027/discussion-between-nullpointer-and-jb-nizet).

Comment: If i change it using the updated code, the block has unhandled exception . Earlier for me the method calling the block was throwing the exception itself, but that wouldn't suffice now.

Comment: As I said, the exception must be a runtime exception. I'll edit my answer once again to show you how to throw it if it's not a runtime exception.